# Magento 2 Design Theme tab is missing

Tags: themes, magento2, magento-2.0

[image]

Hi, I am trying magento 2 and struggling to install the new theme. Because Design Theme is not showing under Stores > Configuration > Design.

Answer (score 5):

It has been moved to Content/Design/Configuration

Comment: this should be in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It has been moved to Content/Design/Configuration.
[check screenshot for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHB6z.png)

Then you can select specific store if you have multi store. click edit action and in new window you can find search engine robots setting.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.0.x, you can configure the theme in `Stores > Configuration > Design`.

However, from Magento 2.1.x, this configuration is relocated in `Content > Design > Configuration`. Edit the theme currently in used, and select the newly installed theme.

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/k73aq5)