# How to activate the custom theme in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have recently installed magento Community edition of 2.1 version just want to integrate the custom theme.I made vendor and theme as like magento 2.0 . And also check the theme is showing in magento admin panel in content setting but when i going to activate it in path
store -> configuration -> design there is no options for "Design Theme" where i can activate it.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found it , Now you can activate your theme in content -> configuration and edit your theme and select applied theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 Design Theme tab is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116124/magento-2-design-theme-tab-is-missing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate the theme in **Content > Design > Configuration** in the admin.

The files that your theme must contain are:

1. registration.php
2. theme.xml
3. dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

Comment: This is not the right location in 2.1. It should be content -> design -> configuration